# How do I redirect the response from a Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

hello i want to redirect to a page from _layout.htmlcs using razor view....

I have tried many things to make response.Redirect work but failed...

```c#
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
  <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
      @if (User.IsInRole("Admin")){
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Admin/AddAccount");
      }
      if (User.IsInRole("User")){
```

Respnse.redirect may work properly or its alter native must be used ...

Comment: Can you explain why you want to have a redirect in the layout view? This type of logic belongs in the `Controller`

Comment: You cannot redirect from within a view. The response is already being returned by that point. This is an XY problem. What is it that you're *actually* trying to solve? This is not the right way.

Answer (score 2):

A view is just intended to render a page. It's presumed that if you get to this step, it's already been determined that this is the page you want to render.

If you want to redirect then you would return a [`RedirectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.redirectresult) instead of a `ViewResult` from your controller method. There are a few methods that return a `RedirectResult` like

```
Redirect(someUrl);
RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName)
```

...and others, and overloads of these.

I recommend `RedirectToAction` because even though it will compile if you get the values wrong, Visual Studio at least gives you a visual indication that the controller and action you're referring to exist.

Whatever conditions you're checking in the view to determine if you want to redirect, just check them in the controller instead.

Comment: I want to redirect from Razor view, how i can remove this error from view for Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Admin/AddAccount");, I just want to make it work, or alternative is also fine...., Thanks

Comment: The controller decides what to return -`ViewResult`, `RedirectResult`, or something else. The only way to "redirect" from the view is if the page loads, and then when it loads it redirects. You could do that by writing JavaScript or a meta tag to the page. But that would be awful and there's no reason to do it. If you have the information in the view to decide that you want to redirect, you have that same information in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a asp-page="/Admin/AddAccount">Add Account</a>`